# MalformedURLException when uploading file to VPS via FTP

Tags: java, ftp, vps, uploading

I'm having some trouble uploading a file to my VPS (centos 6 64 bit) via FTP. The FTP I'm using is called Pure-FTPD and am trying to upload an image using Java. The error code I get is

> java.net.MalformedURLException: For input string: "*VPS PASS HERE*@9X.XXX.2XX.X8"
>       at java.net.URL.(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URL.(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URL.(Unknown Source)
>       at FtpUrlUpload.main(FtpUrlUpload.java:25)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "*VPS PASS HERE*@9X.XXX.2XX.X8"
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URLStreamHandler.parseURL(Unknown Source)
>       ... 4 more

Here is my full code.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class FtpUrlUpload {

private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ftpUrl = "ftp://%s:%s@%s/%s;type=i";
    String host = "9X.XXX.2XX.X8";
    String user = "VPS USERNAME HERE";
    String pass = "VPS PASS HERE";
    String filePath = "C:\\Users\\user\\desktop\\Untitled.png";
    String uploadPath = "public_html/Untitled.png";

    ftpUrl = String.format(ftpUrl, user, pass, host, uploadPath);
    System.out.println("Upload URL: " + ftpUrl);

    try {
        URL url = new URL(ftpUrl);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();

        System.out.println("File uploaded");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is due to spaces in the username / password not being encoded correctly?

try using URI.toURL()

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html

Comment: There is no spaces in the username/pass it's one phrase. Also do you mean using URI.toURL() in the line     ftpUrl = String.format(ftpUrl, user, pass, host, uploadPath); for the user and pass?